# Hyperlink to download a file when clicked, and increment a field for each download that takes place

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, hyperlink

I have an SQL statement that outputs a table of teaching resources stored on a MySQL database. I can output the list of teaching resources in a table, that's fine. I can use a series of hyperlinks, one for each teaching resource, so that when you click on the hyperlink, it downloads the resource. The code for this is below:

```
echo '<a href="'.($row['resource_name_path']).'?res_id='.$row['resource_id'].'"style="color:#900">'.htmlspecialchars($row['hyperlink_resource_name']).'</a>';
```

However, each time someone clicks on the hyperlink, I don't just want the resource to be downloaded, but I want a 'no of downloads' field to be incremented by one in the MySQL database each time a teaching resource is downloaded. This would let you know how many times each teaching resource had been downloaded to see which is the most popular. Question is how?

The hyperlink above allows the download of the teaching resource to take place, but then how do I 'allow the download' and run an SQL statement to update the no of downloads' field??? Can I run a PHP function, calling it using javascript, without leaving the page??

This appears to be like mission impossible for me, so any advice would be grateful and it's the first time on here, so go easy !!

Comment: You could make the link go to a PHP page, which can increment the download by 1 with a query, and then redirect to the download link with `header('Location:'.htmlspecialchars($row['hyperlink_resource_name']))`
and they won't even know it incremented it :)

Comment: Also, maybe you could make the link be `echo '<a href="file.php?dl='.htmlspecialchars($row['hyperlink_resource_name'])).'">Link</a>` and then you can use `$_GET['dl']`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run a php script using javascript to update the MySql table. Use AJAX to do it so that you don't have to leave the page.

Try googling AJAX code example to know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought...but I really dislike incrementing a count field in any database.  What updated it is not always clear and the counts can go sideways with 0 paper trail to troubleshoot why.  Instead of incrementing a field, why not create a table called 'downloads' or something to that extent that holds a single row for every download along with an ID to map it to the resource being downloaded.  To get the total download count from this set up, use a simple select id, count(1) from table group by id.

You still need to run an 'insert' statement when the link is clicked, so this doesn't really work as an answer to your question....but now you'd have a table with one row per download that can be readily viewed as verification to your download count number